# How to leave only given characters in a file?

Tags: sed

**Q:** How can I leave only the following characters in a file?

- the ASCII decimal 10, the ENTER, so the so called "line feed"
- ASCII printable characters (character code 32-127)
- The extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255)

We need it to clear text files that contains many garbage..

Example garbage chars:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
$ printf 'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép\n'
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
$ 
$ printf 'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép\n' | tr -dc '[\x0A\x20-\xFF]' && echo
rvtrtkrfrgp
$
```

Comment: Byte values 10, 32-127, 128-255, (where the allowed value range is 0 through 255) will leave you with "pretty much everything" anyway. Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't know what is the ex.: Byte value of the question mark in white on the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really after is this:

```
% strings -e S ./hello
```

From the manual page:

> For each *file* given, GNU **strings** prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.

Since you have non-ASCII characters: The option `-e S` tells **strings** to look for 8-bit characters instead of the default (regular ASCII). Obviously it raises the frequency of extracting random strings that *look* like 8-bit text.

If you're only working with compiled executables (as it seems from your screen capture), look at the manual page; **strings** is designed to extract strings from compiled code, so it has several options designed around that scenario.

Comment: strings removed "á" too.

Comment: Hmm. Can you establish or demonstrate *for certain* whether the strings in question are in Latin-1, UTF-8, or something else? `od -c`, or even `cat -v`, is one way. The task is not hard if you know the correct encoding. (I'm wondering if @Adrian is correct and you're mistaken about "á" being encoded in "extended ASCII").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl`:

```
perl -Mutf8 -ple 's/\P{IsPrint}//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ head -c 500 /bin/ls | tr -dc '[\x0A\x20-\xFF]' && echo
ELF>E@@p@8@@@@@@88@8@@@aaaaTT@T@DDPtdggAgAQtd
```

Comment: @evachristine I updated my answer according to your edit, is this what you are after?

Comment: nope, it's not good yet, it removes characters example: "á" - that is the extended ASCII 225 (in decimal)

Comment: My guess is that you are dealing with UTF8-encoded data and thus `á` is represented as `0xC3 0xA1` which is obviously not extended ASCII and thus outside the range you gave. The command works properly, it's your question that is not in accordance with your data.